# Taskbar Windows 11 not visible in some applications on non primary monitors

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

When running some applications in Windows 11 in FullWindow modus such as:

- Firefox
- Telegram
- Etc

The Taskbar in Windows 11 is not visible on all monitors that are not the primary monitor. My monitors have all different resolutions. The application "overlaps" the taskbar.

Quite irritating. I played with compatibility settings but nogo. Somehow I managed to get Firefox to now work correctly on monitor 3 but on monitor 2 it still overlaps the task bar.
Telegram however does not work on monitor 3 and monitor 2.

Is this an existing bug / is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Did you enable (Taskbar settings) Show taskbar on all monitors?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TIKmJxK.png